# Using jQuery and LazyHighCharts in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I am using [this method](http://sumanranjanpanda.wordpress.com/tag/lazy-high-charts-with-rails/) to create a pie chart.

I have it showing inside my View, and what I want to do is when I click on a slice of the pie chart, it would generate three more charts based on the slice it is clicked. Currently, I'm stuck on the very first step - I can't get the click event on the pie chart.

I have the following script (jQuery is properly set up), but I don't know what element to use (which class, which id, which tag) to call it. I tried doing Element Inspection in the browser, but all the results that I thought would be relevant still give nothing (I use hover because it seems to work more frequently than .click, which is another side question)

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#highcharts-3").hover(function(){
        alert("Hello. The document is loaded");
    });
});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that gem, but have you tried to set `plotOptions.pie.point.events.click` ?

Should be something like that in a View:

```
<%= high_chart(“my_pie_div”, @chart) do |c| %>
  <%= raw “options.plotOptions.pie.point.events.click = function() { alert("clicked!") }” %>
<% end %>
```